# in my rspec test suite, how can I populate a static table with config data my app uses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures

So far I use rspec and factories only, not fixtures or seed data. But now I need a (static) Coupon table with a dozen or so records of config data to be available to my app when running my integration tests (rspec + capybara, not cuke).

My rspec tests have a FactoryGirl factory that creates a Store.

In my app, when a Store is initialized by init_store(coupon_code), a coupon code is passed in that turns on/off various features (by looking up the settings for that coupon in Coupon table).

So, when I create a Store factory, I also need to specify (via trait?) a coupon code. Then, down in my model, the method that initializes a store will use the coupon code to lookup a bunch of settings in the Coupon table. (Each coupon has about 20 attributes that turn on/off various Store features.)

My coupons.yml file contains the actual coupon table data used by my app. Now I need to make them available to the app when tests are being run. (Don't care about 'brittle', this table doesn't change.)

Having not used fixtures OR seed data with rspec, I'm not sure how/where to put my coupons.yml file and how to make the coupons 'load' into the test Coupon table so they are available to my app while tests are running.

Do I pre-populate seed data with coupons.yml? If so, how can I have that get loaded into my test database each time my tests run?

Or, should I use fixtures?

Either way, where should coupons.yml go and how do I load it (in the Store factories? in one of the specs? In specs_helper?)

When I search for stuff like "using fixtures and factories" or "using seed data with rspec" all I find is the advice "use factories" and yeah, I get that. But for this particular situation I need both, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do something like this, and I use seeds rather than fixtures (though I'm sure you could use fixtures too).

In spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  ...

  config.before :suite do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[table1 table2]}
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
    Rails.application.load_seed
  end

  ...

end
```

So the DatabaseCleaner.strategy line is telling database_cleaner to clean everything except the array of tables you pass it.

After setting the strategy, you simply call `Rails.application.load_seed` to load the seed data.

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: this looks great - had not heard of the except for databasecleaner - I'll try it this weekend and check back in to accept